# How to insert "<?php include("Login.php");?>" in a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to realize a dynamic website for exercise. All contents are stored in the database:
I included html code(FORMS) as DB content with no ploblem, but when i try to insert php code as DB content nothing happens. The field type for Content is TEXT.
I tryed various ways :

```
INSERT INTO TableContent(Name_Content, Content, ID_Menu) values ("Amministration Area", "<?php include('LogIn.php')", 5);
INSERT INTO TableContent(Name_Content, Content, ID_Menu) values ("Amministration Area", "<?php include(\"LogIn.php\")", 5);
```

In the website page i see Amministrazion Area, but not what Login.php does.
I thought i made a mistake in Login.php page code so i changed it in a simply  echo ("Hi"); but nothing appears anyway. I see only the text Amministration Area.
How can i solve it ?

Comment: it's not a good practice to insert the php code in database. later it will be difficult to manage

Comment: Thanks, you're right I'll follow this advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just text! Text in a database. Nothing happens when you just insert text into a database and read from it. You have to actually get something to *execute* that text as PHP code. That doesn't happen automatically, thankfully! In PHP, the way to execute arbitrary strings as code is by using [`eval`](http://php.net/eval). But this is overall a very bad idea; storing all PHP code in a database is not making anything easier, on the contrary it makes everything more difficult to work with and more prone to exploits if you execute arbitrary code. I'd advice you to stop doing that and go back to PHP code in .php files, not databases.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I'll follow your advice, PHP code in .php files!

Answer (score 1):

PHP see `<?php include("LogIn.php");?` as a string, when you look in the source code of your file, you'll probably see it. It doesn't show up on screen because it starts with a `<`.

To execute the code instead of handling it as a string, you can use the [eval()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function.

You however don't want every row of your database be seen as PHP code, so you'll probably need to add a extra column that defines what the row is, i.e. a string, php code. Or you make an extra table where you store your includes.